# Empty 'thebibliography' environment

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing a scientific article using LaTeX, with a separate .bib bibliography file, generated via a Zotero Firefox extension collection.

When generating the .pdf document, I get the following error:

> Empty 'thebibliography' environment on input line 3

The line 3 contains:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Thus, the Reference section is empty and every citation number in the text appears as [?].
I already tried several things:

- Inserting a `\nocite{*}` in the document
- Changing var `= {something}` to var `= {"something"}` in the BibTex file
- Removing all Unicode characters from the BibTex file

But the error style persist.
Any idea?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. I'd guess it is line 3 of the .bbl file, not the .tex file. Have you run `bibtex`? Edit: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number for some more explanation about how the system works.

Comment: Thanks for your link! Its read was really useful to understand the problem.
I actually solved it: I switched to a Linux running computer and used LaTeXila, which when running "latex" prompted that it skipped lookind in the .bib file because of a space in its name. So I renamed it and now everything compile just fine.